# Rails 3 "Could not find activesupport-3.2.3 in any of the sources"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, bundler, activesupport

Helo. I recently reformatted my Mac to a fresh install of Lion, and then upgraded to Mountain Lion. I installed homebrew and installed ruby and put usr/local/bin before usr/bin in my path. I used gem to install rails, bundler, and I ran bundle install on my app. The app bundles successfully, however when I go to start the application I get the error

> Could not find activesupport-3.2.3 in any of the sources

despite the fact that bundle install claims that the gem successfully installed, and gem install activesupport -v 3.2.3 succeeds as well. If I do install activesupport then I prompted with the next gem to install.

bundle exec rails s gives me a different, very long error that begins with:

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle: [BUG]
>   Segmentation fault ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410)
>   [x86_64-darwin12.1.0]

Which seems to have something to do with postgres. Anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have the Postgres dev headers installed?

Comment: Well I figured out the first problem was that I was specifying the wrong version of rails in my Gemfile. After updating it to my current version it still tells me I'm missing gems one after the other, even though a bundle install claims they've succeeded.

In response to mu is too short, 1.8 is the version of Gem, not ruby.

Comment: Ähm, nope; the 1.8 in this macosx system path DOES suggest, that there is a ruby 1.8 version involved.

Comment: Doh! You're right Atastor. Cheers.